# The view 'Whatever' or its master could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

All of a sudden in this MVC site I have no views that can be found.

```
The view 'LoginUltraMind' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/MyAccount/LoginUltraMind.aspx
~/Views/MyAccount/LoginUltraMind.ascx
~/Views/Shared/LoginUltraMind.aspx
~/Views/Shared/LoginUltraMind.ascx
~/Views/MyAccount/storeNoNav.master
~/Views/Shared/storeNoNav.master
```

These files definitely exist at these locations -I am looking right at them!  I updated to RC 1 yesterday and ran the site fine after that with 0 problems.  Today I come back to it and this happens.. grr.....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up I had 2 Pages sections in my web.config located in the views directory.  I guess when I upgraded I wasn't paying attention and didn't see the previous  section.  Totally idiot maneuver on my part, but I do wish the error thrown would have told me that instead of a list of files it couldn't find.

Comment: So what exactly did you do to fix this? I have the same problem and I see some entries in the web.config. Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use fiddler to see exactly what is being requested. It is probably an issue resolving your web application base address.

Comment: I watch the VS debugger go through the code and the proper controller and function inside the controller is being called by the browser, the return view() is where it throws this error.  i watch with fiddler just to be sure though

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this problem and determined it was caused because I tried to access the 'Model' object on the declaration part of the page (directly on the `<script runat="server">` section, outside of the *Page Load* event). The error raised indicating that the page doesn't exist is completely misleading in this case... Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem before. Today it happened again but with a view that it is called by other methods and I knew it worked. I traced the code and found that I had an erroneous path in my button. But I'm still in the dark as to why the button still hits my method in the correct folder. Here is the code for the two buttons. Notice the reference paths. The view area engine was looking in the wrong folder. (the correct path is the top one, Admin.mvc is wrong)
"
                        id="EditClientManager" title="Client Manager Editor">
                        Edit
                    
                    
                    href="/Admin.mvc/AccessControl/ClientManagersDelete/<%=Convert.ToString(manager.Id)%>"
                    id="DeleteApprover" title="Client Manager Editor">
                        Delete

Comment: sorry the top part got cut off.

Comment: <a class="actionButton styled box iframe_modal hasMax hasMin hasNewWin"  enableviewstate="true"                            href= "/AccessControl.mvc/AccessControl/ClientManagersEdit/<%=Convert.ToString(manager.Id)%>