# The view or it's master was not found, but it exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have read [The view 'Whatever' or its master could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493369/the-view-whatever-or-its-master-could-not-be-found) and [ASP.NET MVC The view 'name' or its master was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226514/asp-net-mvc-the-view-name-or-its-master-was-not-found) but I cannot find the solution to my problem.  The **file exists in the directory**, but it says it does not:

> The view 'GetLastArticle' or its master was not found or no view
>   engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/Article/GetLastArticle.aspx
>   ~/Views/Article/GetLastArticle.ascx ~/Views/Shared/GetLastArticle.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/GetLastArticle.ascx
>   ~/Views/Article/GetLastArticle.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Article/GetLastArticle.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/GetLastArticle.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/GetLastArticle.vbhtml

It points to this line of the following code:

`@Html.Action("GetLastArticle", "Article")`

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Home Page"
End Code

<h2>My Blog <span>news</span></h2>
<div class="info_box_holder fltleft">
    @Html.Action("GetLastRssItem", "Rss", New With {.url = "http://rss.ew.com/web/ew/rss/todayslatest/index.xml"})
    @Html.Action("GetLastRssItem", "Rss", New With {.url = "http://www.eonline.com/syndication/feeds/rssfeeds/movies.xml"})
    </div>
    <div class="info_box_holder fltleft">
    @Html.Action("GetLastArticle", "Article")
    @Html.Action("GetLastRssItem", "Rss", New With {.url = "http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment"})
    </div>
```

Here is my action that I am calling and getting the error on:

```
    Function GetLastArticle() As ActionResult
        Dim models = db.Articles.OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.DateCreated)
        Dim model = New Article
        If models.Any Then
            model = db.Articles.OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.DateCreated).First
        Else
            model.DateCreated = Date.Today
            model.Title = "Latest article not found"
            model.Body = "The latest article was not found."
        End If
        Return View(model)
    End Function
```

**The site works fine on localhost, but when I publish, I get the error.  How can I fix this?**

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the view is being published along with the rest of the site?  Have you tried renaming the view and function as a test?

Comment: Your comment is the answer.  For some reason, despite the file being included in the project, it wasn't getting published.  I excluded it, then included it again, and finally, I published and it worked.  Thanks for your help, very much.

Comment: Awesome - I have had a few like that as well, usually from a wicked merge or something though from source control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that Visual Studio is actually publishing the file to the remote web server.  If the file is not included in the solution or if the build action has been changed from 'Content' mistakenly, then the file will not exist on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This same issue was resolved when I changed the 'Build Action' from 'None' to 'Content' in Visual Studio. Look in the page properties to change the Build Action value. Rebuild the project and updated the server